# Tutorials to customize Tableau legend

Tags: legend, tableau-api

Here is my [Data Viz](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/logarithmic_order_quantity/logarithmic_order_quantity)

I wish to customize legends as below

[image]

Here is what I have. Having difficulty finding tutorials (on google) for customizing legends. Please assist.

[image]

Comment: You can customize legends to a certain degree, but not like what you show at the top. That "legend" is simply another sheet that was created to look like a legend. You can create that, but you would need to put both sheets onto a dashboard to display them together.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to making color and shap both are in legends.but it is possible we have to create new sheet and making customize legends.

Refer this site :

http://www.analytics-tuts.com/manual-legends-tableau/

I hope you helpfull this site........